# How to get all text from PDF as String using Fox It Reader SDK Activex control

Tags: .net, winforms, foxitembeddedsdk

I have COM component:  `private AxFoxitPDFSDKProLib.AxFoxitPDFSDK axFoxitPDFSDK1;`. I loaded PDF into it:

```
public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        axFoxitPDFSDK1.OpenFile("C:/cw3_31paz.pdf", null);
    }
```

I would like to get all text from inside of this PDF as `String`. I couldn't find any method to do it, but I have found method `axFoxitPDFSDK1.GetSelectedText();` but didn't find `selectAll()` to select everything

Answer (score 0):

The Foxit ActiveX SDK has method BSTR GetPageText (long nPageIndex)
So you just iterate trough all pages calling this function and adding the output from the function to your string variable.
If you need more information look into the manual pdf file that is installed with the ActiveX.